# What is the fastest way to compose a target function from a finite set of existing functions

Tags: function, math, optimization, function-composition

Given a finite set of functions and two numbers A and B, what is the fastest way to determine the composite function that satisfies `f(A) = B`?

For example, if we have:

```
functions = {
    f1(x) = x - 1,
    f2(x) = x + 1,
    f3(x) = x * x
}
```

and
`A = 1, B = 9`

Then the optimal solution would be: `f(x) = f3(f2(f2(x)))`. Because `f(A) = B` and the function is composed of as few functions as possible.

The fastest solution to solve might not be the optimal one -- any advice on either fronts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are those functions `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` fixed? So do we write an algorithm that knows those are our functions to work with? Because if you wanted to have a variable list of functions, this question is quite impossible to answer.

Comment: If real numbers are allowed (which is usually assumed when talking about functions), then most pairs `A,B` will not have a solution for your given functions at all, e.g in your case if `A` is integral and `B` is not, like `A=1, B=1.1`. But also if you restrict the domain to integers and take the functions `f1(x) = 4 * x` and `f2(x) = x * x` you will, for instance, never reach values for `B` like `2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, ...` no matter what value for `A` is given. So the search will most of the time be endless if not more information about the functions is known beforehand.

Comment: @MikePierce Yes, the functions in the set would be constant, although I was wondering if there was a general solution that would work no matter the functions in the set.

Comment: @coproc Is there any way to quickly verify whether or not the search is endless? What if in addition to the original set of functions, you're also provided the inverses?

Comment: If it's always those three functions then the search is not endless. But that appears to not be the case by your other comment. So yeah, this question is impossible to answer in general without any conditions on the functions. Monotone, injective, surjective, or hypothesis like that may make this question possible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

In your example, start at `A=1` and calculate `f1(1) = 0`, `f2(1) = 2`, and `f3(1) = 1`. Then continue from there (`f1(0), f2(0), f3(0), f1(2), ...`) until you reach `B`. Ignore numbers that have previously been calculated.
This will yield the optimal solution if there is one.

If `A` and `B` are both integers, there is always a solution of the form `f1(f1(...f1(A)...)` or `f2(f2(...f2(A)...)`, so the search is not endless.